# (Android-Java) Horizontal RecyclerView Reloads images on scroll

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview

I'm recently trying to use a horizontal RecyclerView and when i load images with 
Picasso and other similar services the images are shown correctly but when i scroll the Recycler view all the ImageView get refreshed and reloaded for a second.
It doesn't happen in the Vertical Mode
Here's what's happening:
http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=122kxev%3E&s=9#.V4ZWuuiLShc

and the code I use to load the image:

```
                            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder() .cacheInMemory(true)
                                .cacheOnDisk(true).build();
                        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url, into, options);
```